# Delete function not working with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, mongodb

my js code:

```
camListApp.controller("Hello", function($scope, $http, $uibModal){

    $scope.del=function(data){

        var result=confirm('are you sure?');
        if(result==true){
        var index=getSelectedIndex(data);
        $scope.records.splice(index, 1);
        }
        };
        function getSelectedIndex(data) {
        for (var i =0; i<$scope.records.length; i++)
        if($scope.records[i].data==data)
        return i;
        return -1;
        }
```

Html code:

```
  <td><button class="btn" ng-click="del(record.filename)">Delete</button></td>
```

My json data:

```
[{"cameraid":"000000001","timestamp":"2016-07-09 10:06","filename":"c037731fc2256177ba29c7893caacf04","locationid":"Bedok01"}   
{"cameraid":"000000003","timestamp":"2016-07-13 11:35","filename":"4fd2413d30073b4b6a5cacbb8b7c1965","locationid":"Bedok01"} 
{"cameraid":"000000003","timestamp":"2016-07-13 14:41","filename":"6b6b62948eb679efeb650d609c85b7aa","locationid":"Bedok01"}
```

How can i do a delete function on angularjs and when the button is clicked and at the same time mongodb also remove the data. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make http call to delete from db  and then remove the object from list using splice as below

```
<td><button class="btn" ng-click="del(record)">Delete</button></td>

$scope.del = function(record) {
var index = $scope.records.indexOf(record);
$scope.records.splice(index , 1);
    $scope.list();
};
```

Comment: Sorry is able to remove on my gui itself but the data does not remove in mongodb

Comment: As i stated above you have to make an http call to remove it from db you may use $http.post if you web service doesn't have delete controller

Comment: So do i need to create one more controller on my rest web service for delete? Or there is other method in doing it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to open an endpoint in your server. Mongodb is a database and thus you can access it from your backend, by implementing a controller or something similar. Then you can make an API call to that endpoint.

```
 $scope.del = function(data) {
       $http.post('/records/' + data.id + '/delete')
        .then(function(){
           .... the rest of your angular code goes here
       })
   };
```

Comment: But my rest web service does not have delete controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350764/how-to-remove-data-on-mongodb-with-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment64114390_38350764

Comment: @AlvinWee why you did not accept my answer since it's the one that shows how to make the API call ? :P