# How to remove data in mongodb with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, mongodb

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/camera")
public class RecordController {

@Autowired
RecordRepository rep;
@RequestMapping(value="store") //controller for store

public  String  camera (@RequestParam(value="cam",required=true) String cameraid,
        @RequestParam(required=true, value="ts") String timestamp,
        @RequestParam(value="fn",required=true) String filename,
        @RequestParam(value="location",required=true, defaultValue="Bedok01") String locationid)
{
    try 
    {
        Record cam = new Record(cameraid, ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime(timestamp), filename, locationid);
        rep.save(cam);
        return "OK";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        String errorMessage;
        errorMessage = ex + " <== error";
        return ("error: " + ex.getMessage());}
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="list") //controller for retrieve all data
    public List<Record> getList() 
    {
        List<Record> recordList = rep.findAll(); 
        return recordList;
    }
}
```

My json data:

```
[{"cameraid":"000000001","timestamp":"2016-07-09 10:06","filename":"c037731fc2256177ba29c7893caacf04","locationid":"Bedok01"}   
{"cameraid":"000000003","timestamp":"2016-07-13 11:35","filename":"4fd2413d30073b4b6a5cacbb8b7c1965","locationid":"Bedok01"} 
{"cameraid":"000000003","timestamp":"2016-07-13 14:41","filename":"6b6b62948eb679efeb650d609c85b7aa","locationid":"Bedok01"}
```

My js code for delete:

```
camListApp.controller("Hello", function($scope, $http, $uibModal){

    $scope.del = function (record) {
        $http['delete']('/camera/list/?' + record.filename).success(function(response) {
             $scope.records.splice($scope.records.indexOf(record), 1);

        });
    };
```

Html code:

```
       <td><button class="btn" ng-click="del(record)">Delete</button></td>
```

I trying to remove data in mongodb when i click on the delete button but with my current code, i only able to remove the data on my gui itself but not in the mongodb. So anybody can help me with this?

Comment: This could have *something* to do with the fact that you didn't write the corresponding back-end code that would handle the delete request. The "/camera/list/" endpoint will return a list of cameras, as it stands. You'd need to add the DELETE support to your "/camera/" endpoint.

Comment: So i have to add a delete controller too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38347353/1240557

Comment: @kryger thats my previous question ...

Comment: Oh can you help me with this question?

Comment: First result for "spring rest delete": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340599/how-to-handle-restful-delete-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @kryger i don't really understand those code. Is it possible if you post an answer with my question instead?

Comment: It's impossible to tell *which* part of the linked answer is not clear to you, making it tricky to offer tailored advice. Maybe you should take a step back and start with some basic [Spring Getting Started Guides](https://spring.io/guides)?